# How can I increase /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail

Tags: random, entropy

I have access to genuine random numbers - random.org, for example.

I have a number of processes using `/dev/random` and my value for `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` is `143`, which is pretty low.

I'd like to have a process that monitors `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` and, when it drops below about `3000`, tops it up.

How can I incorporate the random numbers from random.org into `/dev/random` so that entropy_avail increases?

Answer (score 4):

**Do not use an online source of entropy!**

If your system currently has insufficient entropy, then it will not be able to make a secure connection to random.org and any material you download from it will not be secret. Furthermore, you should not be using the blocking device anyway. It's perfectly fine to use `/dev/urandom`, no matter how low the entropy estimate is. If for whatever reason you are using a program that is foolishly using the blocking device, you can keep it topped off by installing `haveged`, a daemon that attempts to generate random data from memory latency. Please see https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom for more.

If you still want to shoot yourself in the foot, then you can use an [IOCTL](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) on the random character device to adjust the entropy estimate. From [`random(4)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html), the `RNDADDENTROPY` IOCTL is what you want:

```
RNDADDENTROPY
       Add some additional entropy to the input pool, incrementing
       the entropy count.  This differs from writing to /dev/random
       or /dev/urandom, which only adds some data but does not incre‐
       ment the entropy count.  The following structure is used:

           struct rand_pool_info {
               int    entropy_count;
               int    buf_size;
               __u32  buf[0];
           };

       Here entropy_count is the value added to (or subtracted from)
       the entropy count, and buf is the buffer of size buf_size
       which gets added to the entropy pool.
```

This IOCTL requires the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` [capability](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) to function.

---

Very related:

- [Linux kernel entropy - does it matter to /dev/urandom and what is a minimum?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/86430/106285)
- [Feeding /dev/random entropy pool?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/89/106285#7074)
- [Is a rand from /dev/urandom secure for a login key?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/3936/106285)
- [Is "always use /dev/urandom" still good advice in an age of containers and isolation?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/186086/106285)

Comment: Adding online entropy source probably doesn't really warrant such a strongly worded warning. AFAIU it doesn't really hurt to add entropy from an online source of entropy, at worst it'll just give you fuzzy feeling because your entropy_avail value appears higher, but it shouldn't cause the output of your /dev/(u)random to be any less unpredictable. So while it may be useless if the attacker controls one of your entropy source, it wouldn't really be harmful?

Comment: @LieRyan You're correct, but only because of how a quirk of the Linux kernel random driver works. Generally, getting random data from an online source is a terrible idea. It's for the same reason that I would warn strongly against homebrew crypto even if OP is planning on cascading it with AES.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the only existing answer to this question explains things that aren't viable, here are a couple of options which might be viable:

1. haveged - https://github.com/jirka-h/haveged, which uses the HAVEGE algorithm described at https://www.irisa.fr/caps/projects/hipsor/; available on Debian/Ubuntu in the package of the same name.
2. rng-tools - uses built-in hardware entropy sources and (optionally) the Intel/AMD RDRAND instruction; available in Debian/Ubuntu in the packages rng-tools-debian and rng-tools5.

This is not an endorsement of the options listed above, just a note that there may be usable options.  Evaluating their security or randomness quality is an exercise left to the reader. :-)

Note also that in Linux kernel 5.x, changes to the entropy generation in the kernel mean that an algorithm similar to HAVEGE is built in, and `/dev/random` is no longer blocking.  (See the links in the [haveged README](https://github.com/jirka-h/haveged/blob/master/README.md) for details.)

Comment: Actually HAVEGE is not built in, it's a similar algorithm called Jitterentropy (although that's not what's responsible for it being non-blocking). But yeah, haveged works. It uses `RNDADDENTROPY` to increase the entropy count.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect that a bit better.